# Identify components on computer motherboard - cylindrical and cube shapes

Tags: identification, components, computers, motherboard

I'd like to know what components are the ones with blue numbers and the big ones behind them:

[image: image1]

The latter components I'm talking about:

[image: image2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: The ones with blue marking are capacitors. To get anything about the other ones, you'll need to provide a better-lit and more in-focus photo.

Comment: We need better an in focus pictures to be able to help you.

Comment: No, there isn't anything on them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jakob Halskov mentioned, those are 820 uF 25V aluminum electrolytical capacitors.

Those black "tall" components are flat wire iron core inductors, likely configured for the voltage regulators next to them. The `CHOKE` reference designator is proof that it is an inductor.

Answer (score 3):

The silver and blue cylindrical components look like 820 uF 25V electrolytical capacitors.

Comment: OP also asked for the components behind the capacitors as well.

Answer (score 1):

The silver and blue capacitors I think are a Nippon Chemi-Con cap from their NPCAP-PSE series which is what the "E" is calling out. This would be an Aluminum Poly Cap. Looking closly it appear the bottom is a 2.5 and not 25 which would make it part [APSE2R5ELL821MF08S](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/united-chemi-con/APSE2R5ELL821MF08S/565-3252-ND/1948049)